# C# Scope issue with "global" class

Tags: c#, dictionary, scope

I am trying to add what would amount to a global dictionary to some C# code. I know globals don't technically exist in C#, so I am using a static class with no namespace. My code looks like this

```
public static class GlobalClass
{
    public static Dictionary<string,string> Foo = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    public static void Dictionary_Load()
    {
        //Load Dictionary from database.
        // When I break at the end of this function I see the Dictionary has data in it.
    }

    public static string Dictionary_Lookup(input)
    {
        if(Foo.ContainsKey(input))
        {
            string return_string = Foo[input];
            return return_string;
        }else
        {
            return "ERROR";
        }
    }
}
```

In another form I call this class as such:

```
namespace MainFormNamespace
{
    public partial class : MainForm : Form
    {
         ....
     DictionaryLoad();
     string test = DictionaryLookup("Bar") //I know "Bar" is in the dictionary
     .....
     }
}
```

When I run this I set a breakpoint before the return of Dictionary_Load, and at the if statement in Dictionary_Lookup. When I look at the dictionary at the end of Dictionary_Load it is full. When I return to MainForm, the dictionary is empty. When I break at the if statement in Dictionary_Lookup, the dictionary is also empty. I've tried putting the two classes in the same namespace, and that didn't work. Is there something wrong with my scope? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: `Dictionary_Lookup` and `DictionaryLookup` aren't the same thing.

Comment: Also, use `TryGetValue` rather than `ContainsKey` and `[]`.  Also please include **all** code that reads from or writes to `Foo`.

Comment: Provide a program that *actually reproduces the problem* and doesn't have obvious typos like missing underbars and extra colons. Make your program simpler and simpler until either the problem goes away -- which should tell you where it was -- or you have something that fits onto a page that someone can help you with. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a global object for application, use a singleton.

https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Design-Patterns-Singleton

https://github.com/skimedic/presentations/blob/master/Patterns/Creational/Singleton/MySingletonClass.cs

Name your class as DictionaryLoad

```
public static class DictionaryLoad{ }
```

In place of

```
private static volatile MySingletonClass _instance;
```

change it to

```
private static volatile Dictionary<string,string> _instance;
```

In place of

```
_instance = new MySingletonClass();
```

use

```
_instance = new Dictionary<string, string>() and load the dictionary.
```

Use your function like this

```
public static string Dictionary_Lookup(input)
    {   //DictionaryLoad.Instance will return the dictionary now. 

        if(DictionaryLoad.Instance.ContainsKey(input))
        {
            string return_string = DictionaryLoad.Instance[input];
            return return_string;
        }else
        {
            return "ERROR";
        }
    }
```